# Why are cosets of vector spaces called affine subspaces when they are not always a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, affine-geometry

Say $U\leq V$ for a vector space $V$, and $v \space \in \space  V$. We define an *affine subspace* to be a coset of a vector subspace, namely $$v+U=\{v+u | u \space\epsilon\space U\} \subset V$$

However [it can be proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398202/coset-of-w-containing-v-is-a-subspace-of-v-iff-v-in-w) that this is only a subspace when $v \space\in\space U$.

So my question is, in the case when $v \not\in U$, why is the coset of the vector subspace still called an affine subspace when it is not actually a vector space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase "affine subspace" has to be read as a single term. It refers, as you said, to a coset of a subspace of a vector space.  As is common in mathematics, this does not mean that an "affine subspace" is a "subspace" that happens to be "affine" - an "affine subspace" is usually not a subspace at all.

But there is a relationship between affine subspaces and (genuine) subspaces, which is the motivation for the terminology.  Every subspace is an affine subspace, and every affine subspace can be translated to become a subspace. So, geometrically, subspaces and affine subspaces have a similar structure.

There are many other examples in mathematics where this kind of thing happens - where a modifier to a word creates a compound term which refers to something that the original word did not refer to. Another example is a "[skew field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring)", which is not usually a field.

Comment: Could you add a little more on the relationship between affine subspaces and genuine subspaces?

Comment: Every genuine subspace can be written in terms of the 0 vector, (0+U) and so is an affine subspace.